# Android: How to change the colour of menu icons

Tags: android

How can I change the colour of the menu icon on the action bar programmatically, not using styles.xml?

I found a really simple solution, to use the `setTint()` method, but this only seems to apply for the Lollipop and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On phone, will improve later. This should work:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
Drawable drawable = menuItem.getIcon();
if (drawable != null) {
    // If we don't mutate the drawable, then all drawable's with this id will have a color
    // filter applied to it.
    drawable.mutate();
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
}
```

Comment: in this case, what kind of value should the `alpha` variable have?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer you can remove that line if you don't want to change the alpha value.

Comment: Hey thanks! it's finally working as intended. Thank you so much for your tip :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tint in a backwards-compatible way using [`DrawableCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) in the support library. The API requires a bit of wrapper boilerplate to work.

```
MenuItem item = ... // The menu item you want to change color
Drawable icon = item.getIcon();
int tintColor = ... // The color you want, expressed as a color value, not an int resource.
Drawable tintWrapper = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
DrawableCompat.setTint(tintWrapper, tintColor);
item.setIcon(tintWrapper);
```